# Best OOP Practice in C#: Passing the Object as Parameter VS Creating a New Instance of the Object

Tags: programming-practices, object-oriented-design, parameters

First of all, I would like to know if passing an object as parameter is much better than creating another object again in a class that will use it again and second what are the pros and cons of each one?

Here's an example:

```
public class ClassWithTheObject
{

TheObject obj = new TheObject();

// Somewhere around the code
PassTheObjectHere anotherObj = new PassTheObjectHere(obj);

}
```

Or just go straight declaring the class `TheObject` inside the `PassTheObjectHere` class? The case would be that both `ClassWithTheObject` and `PassTheObjectHere` classes will use the `TheObject` class.

Last question, is passing the object too many times causes some bad effects on the program?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: I feel like you've been reading up on [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and are now unsure how to put it into practice. Creating object instances within a class makes code practically untestable. Good code is testable code. Those are my two cents.

Comment: Depends a lot on what kind of class `TheObject` is. If it's something service or policy like, pass it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question shows some misconceptions, I guess: if the alternative to

> passing an object as parameter

is to create a new instance directly in the constructor `PassTheObjectHere`, then you are obviously not using any values/state of the previously created `obj` within `PassTheObjectHere`. If that is the case, it is pretty useless to pass `obj` as a parameter to `PassTheObjectHere`. In fact, in such a case I would typically check if `TheObject` *has* any member variables, which might make it a candidate for a static class (but don't get me wrong, I am not telling the usage of a static class would improve the design here in any way).

On the other hand, if the constructor of `PassTheObjectHere` *needs* the values / state of the previously created `obj` to work properly, it would be plain wrong to have a constructor like this.

```
 PassTheObjectHere()
 {
      var obj = new TheObject();

      // ... do something which expects having obj
      // ... some values provided by the caller
 }
```

(I hope this is obvious).

> can passing the object too many times cause some bad effects on the program?

This is not a question of "too many times". One can pass objects around 1000 times correctly, which is fine, and one time wrong, which is bad. For example, if one passes `obj` to the constructor, and the constructor changes the state of `obj` in a way the caller does not expect (called a "side effect")

```
  PassTheObjectHere(TheObject obj)
  {
       // ... use methods/properties/values of obj 
       // ... for this constructor

       // and finally
       obj.MakeValuesInvalid();
  }
```

and the caller does something like

```
public class ClassWithTheObject
{

   TheObject obj = new TheObject();
   obj.Initialize()
   PassTheObjectHere anotherObj = new PassTheObjectHere(obj);
   obj.MethodWhichExpectsObjToBeValid();
}
```

then the program now has a bug.

Fortunately, one can use one of the following alternatives to protect oneself from that:

1. Avoid the side effect by not changing "obj" within the constructor
2. If one needs to change "obj", they can make a copy beforehand within the constructor.
3. Avoid adding methods to `TheObject` which allow the change of internal state of obj (which is called "immutability")

Number 3 leads to the same code as 1, but with additional protection against introducing unintentional side effects at a later point in time, when `PassTheObjectHere` might be changed.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit more complicated than that.

Firstly, understand the tradeoffs.  If you are going to pass a copy of the object (essentially "pass by value" semantics) rather than a reference to the original object, you are going to take a performance hit.  Whether that hit is justified or not depends on your software's functional requirements.

Secondly, it might make more sense semantically to write methods that accept the object by reference but *return a new object,* rather than modifying the passed object in-place or making a copy of it before passing it to the method.

```
var modified object = ReturnANewObjectFrom(theOriginalObject);
```

When you create and return new objects in this fashion, you are taking advantage of *immutability.*  Wherever immutability makes sense, this makes sense to do.  Programs which utilize immutable objects and data structures are easier to reason about, especially when writing concurrent applications (applications that do more than one thing at a time, usually in separate threads or on separate cores).

Comment: quite an answer... but im looking for a more straight forward answer as I am not that familiar with using immutable objects as of now. thanks anyway...

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the premise: `... is essentially a Copy Constructor`.  Objects are passed by reference* in C# (which this seems to be, although I guess it could be something else).  This code could be as simple example of DI, where does the copy constructor come in, am I missing something? * To be clear, the reference itself is passed by value, but the object referred to is not copied.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the question, OP is not thinking about a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on the context you are working with. In your example, you are sending the TheObject instance to the PassTheObjectHere constructor, this way of working tells me that, inside your PassTheObjectHere instance, you are working with some previous  **initializated data**. So if the ClassWithTheObject is going to share the conversational state of the TheObject instance, you are doing right. Thats what i think

Comment: thanks for sharing your thought. if that would be the case then thank you...